# how to use airflow jinja template in python function?

Tags: python, airflow

Is there a way to apply a jinja template in a python function(print_hello) without using an airflow variable(located in airflow web UI) or a global variable?

```
def print_hello():
    print('{{ds}}')

t_test= PythonOperator(
    task_id='t_test',
    python_callable=print_hello,
    dag=dag
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Airflow < 2.0 you need to use `provide_context=True`

```
def print_hello(**kwargs):
    ds = (str(kwargs['ds'])
    print(ds)
    

t1 = MyPythonOperator(
    task_id='temp_task',
    python_callable=print_hello,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag)
```

You can also do:

```
def print_hello(ds, **kwargs):
    print(ds)
```